# What to do? I am making a simple game(this is a fragment of a code) and it doesnt work right

Tags: javascript

The idea was simple. WHen i push a button it lets oppoSpeed as random number and players speed is always 10. If yourSpeed>=oppoSpeed you attack first. It says that oppoSpeed is undefined but i dont see why. I really want this code to be as simple as this. Can you help?

```
<body>
    
<button onclick="spawnEnemy()">Summon Enemy</button> <!--Here the function is triggered-->
<button class="opponent" id="atak" onclick="attackHim()" style="display:block">Atak</button>
<button class="opponent" id="obrona" onclick="defendFromHim()" style="display:block">Obrona</button>
<button class="opponent" id="ucieczka" onclick="runFromHim()" style="display:block">Ucieczka</button>

<script>

let yourHp=10
let yourSpeed=5
let yourDmg=5
let yourDefence=5



console.log("Twoje statystyki na początek wynoszą: " + "\nHp: "+ yourHp+
"\nSpeed: "+yourSpeed+ "\nDmg: "+yourDmg+"\nDefence: "+yourDefence
)
console.log("---------------")

function spawnEnemy(){ //here its defining oppoSpeed

    let oppoHp=Math.floor(Math.random() * (11))
let oppoSpeed=Math.floor(Math.random() * (11))
let oppoDmg=Math.floor(Math.random() * (11))
let oppoDefence=Math.floor(Math.random() * (11))

    console.log("Statystyki wroga wynoszą: "+ "\nHp: "+oppoHp  +
"\nSpeed: "+oppoSpeed+ "\nDmg: "+oppoDmg+"\nDefence: "+oppoDefence)
console.log("---------------")
}

function attackHim(){
    if(yourSpeed>=oppoSpeed){ //it shows the problem here
oppoHp=oppoHp-2
console.log("Zadałeś obrażenia! Hp przeciwnika wynosi: "+oppoHp)
if(oppoHp<=0){
    console.log("Pokonałeś go! Idź dalej!")
} else if(oppoHp>0){
    yourHp=yourHp-2
    console.log("Otrzymałeś obrażenia! Twoje hp wynosi: "+yourHp)
}
    }else if(yourSpeed<oppoSpeed){
yourHp=yourHp-2
console.log("Otrzymałeś obrażenia! Twoje hp wynosi: "+yourHp)
if(yourHp<=0){
    console.log("Przegrałeś! Koniec gry!")
} else if(yourHp>0){
    oppoHp=oppoHp-2
    console.log("Zadałeś obrażenia! Hp przeciwnika wynosi: "+oppoHp)
}
    }
}




</script>

</body>
```

Comment: you defind oppoSpeed in a different function, the code doesnt recognize it when you are out of the function. google for scope in javascript

Answer (score 1):

You defined oppoSpeed locally inside of your function. That means that it can only be accessed inside of `spawnEnemy` .To fix this problem, declare oppoSpeed outside of the function.
For example:

```
let oppoSpeed = 0;
let oppoHp = 0;
let oppoDmg =0 ;
let oppoDefence = 0; 
function spawnEnemy(){ //here its defining oppoSpeed

  oppoHp=Math.floor(Math.random() * (11))
 oppoSpeed=Math.floor(Math.random() * (11))
 oppoDmg=Math.floor(Math.random() * (11))
 oppoDefence=Math.floor(Math.random() * (11))

    console.log("Statystyki wroga wynoszą: "+ "\nHp: "+oppoHp  +
"\nSpeed: "+oppoSpeed+ "\nDmg: "+oppoDmg+"\nDefence: "+oppoDefence)
console.log("---------------")
}
```

This changes the scope of the variables so that they can be accessed by any function that uses them on this script.